# How two split data with two separated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Have variable like `declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'a=2*b=3*c=4|a=10*b=11*c=12|a=20*b=21*c=22'` want split it to table variable

```
declare @tbl TABLE(a varchar(50),b varchar(50),c varchar(50))
```

Response must be like :

```
a    b     c
2    3     4
10   11    12
20   21    22
```

How to do it ?

Comment: You can't do this in code before it arrives at the database?

Comment: @DavidG no , I must split it in stored procedure and then do something with this data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When order of your fields are always sorted use this:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'a=2*b=3*c=4|a=10*b=11*c=12|a=20*b=21*c=22'

SET @var = REPLACE(@var, '*', ',')
SET @var = 'SELECT ' + REPLACE(@var, '|', ' UNION ALL SELECT ')

EXEC(@var)
```

---

When your result always has three columns, but order of fields can changes:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'a=2*b=3*c=4|b=10*a=11*c=12|a=20*b=21*c=22'

SET @var = REPLACE(@var, '*', ',')
SET @var = 'SELECT a,b,c FROM (SELECT ' + REPLACE(@var, '|', ') DT UNION ALL SELECT a,b,c FROM (SELECT ') + ') DT'

EXEC(@var)
```

Comment: @sgA.t please can you tell me what will be if some data will date like `'a=2*b=3*c=2015-05-06|a=10*b=11*c=12.5|a=20*b=21*c=22'`

Comment: You want to have a variant column and also without having quoted by `'`?

Comment: I write here example @var, in real one now i see and have data like `id=000004650439*dated=22.10.2015*cc=0.27` and using query which you write have an error in dated=22.10.2015. please help me

Comment: I'll post another answer ;).

Comment: ok thank you, or you can edit your answer and i will edit question also

Answer (score 0):

As this is an answer to an advanced question I add another answer:

You can specify *data type* and specially convert to a German datetime and *column names* like this:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'id=000004650439*dated=22.10.2015*cc=0.27|id=000004650440*dated=30.10.2015*cc=10'

SET @var = REPLACE(@var, '*', ''',')
SET @var = REPLACE(@var, '=', '=''') + ''''

SET @var = 'SELECT CAST(Null As bigint) As Col1, CAST(Null As nvarchar(15)) As Col2, CAST(Null As decimal(10,5)) As Col3 UNION ALL SELECT ' + 
           REPLACE(@var, '|', ''' UNION ALL SELECT  ') + ''

SET @var = 'SELECT Col1, CONVERT(datetime, Col2, 104) As Col2, Col3 FROM (' + @var + ') DT WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL'
EXEC(@var)
```